# Upgrading Angular 2 -> Angular 4. Can I still inject FirebaseRef?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

When I was using AngularFire 2 (v `2.0.0-beta.4`), I was able to import FirebaseRef in order to utilize functions like `.once` and to use the storage functionality.

An example of where I would do this would be the following:

```
import { FirebaseRef} from "angularfire2";

constructor(@Inject(FirebaseRef) fb) {

// Set reference to the firebase storage
    this.fbStorage = fb.storage();

    // Set a reference to the firebase database
    this.fbDB = fb.database();

}
```

The only problem is that now when I try to import FirebaseRef, it says `Cannot find name AngularFireDatabase`.

Is there a way I can still maintain this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply import `firebase` itself now instead of injecting `FirebaseRef` from `angularFire2` to access the native firebase.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

this.fbStorage = firebase.storage()
this.fbDB = firebase.database()
```